# How to create a transaction using web3 or ethers.js without setting private_key

Tags: blockchain, web3js, ethers.js

**What i am trying to do:**

Building a small app that allows a user to purchase a service for a set amount of tokens. For example, 100 tokens for service A, 500 tokens for service B. This will be for a custom token on the harmony blockchain.

**What i know:**
I already know how to connect to metamask and get the users address. Signer and provider are available to me.

**What confuses me:**
Examples and documentation all refer to a private_key and creating a wallet, i don't need to do that, i need to use the users existing wallet.

**What i need to do:**

1. Prompt a transaction in the user wallet (harmony one or metamask) for a set amount of tokens.
2. Check if the user has required balance (seems trivial knowing i can read their balance).
3. Make the transaction. Also seems ok after reading the docs.
4. Get a receipt, then call a callback/my code. Again, seems ok after reading the docs.

All pretty straight forward, but again - every document i read always refers to setting a private key - surely i don't need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transaction **always** needs to be signed by a private key generating the sender address. Otherwise it's rejected by the network.

> *Examples and documentation all refer to a private_key and creating a wallet, i don't need to do that, i need to use the users existing wallet.*
>
> *every document i read always refers to setting a private key - surely i don't need to do this?*

A backend approach is to import the private key to the app and use it to sign the transaction.

However, there's also a frontend approach: Send a request to a wallet browser extension to sign the transaction and broadcast it to the network. The wallet extension then pops up a window and lets the user chose whether they want to sign the transaction (with their private key, not shared with the app) and broadcast it - or not.

You can find an example of such request in the [MetaMask docs page](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#example).

An advantage of this approach is that your app doesn't need to ask for the user's private key. A disadvantage is that if the user haven't installed a browser wallet compatible with your app, they can't send the transaction (or at least not so easily).

---

*Note: I'm not familiar with the Harmony wallet, but I'm assuming it works in a similar way as MetaMask - because Harmony is an EVM-compatible network, and MetaMask only supports EVM-compatible networks.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its the private key that confused me, as surely i don't need to hard code one into the app? Even if i did, who's private key would that be, i'm not making any sense of it. 

Your front-end approach there is essentially what i need to do - simply set a token and amount, have the user accept (or not), send the TX, get a receipt, call more of my code on success...

Comment: There's a different use case for the private key stored in the app (usually in a separate encrypted database - not hardcoded in the app code). For example a bot that is supposed perform to automated actions - providing a contract with real-life data, trading, .... In this case you don't want to be asked to manually sign the transaction each time. It's usually a private key of the developer/team that created the contract or is now maitaining the app (e.g. if you run your own trading bot, you're likely going to trade with your own account).

Comment: Understood. So in my case i ignore that part of the examples/documentation and can just use the "signer" that is created from the user wallet..?

Comment: @Stuart correct